# why executing sql script shows different constraint in the design view

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I have executed the following script in sql server management studio.

```
create table Accounts_RolePermissions
(
    RoleID int not null,
    PermissionID int not null,
    Primary key(RoleID,PermissionID),
    Foreign key(RoleID) references Accounts_Roles(RoleID),
    Foreign key(PermissionID) references Accounts_Permissions(PermissionID)
)
```

But when clicked the design option on the table it shows that only RoleID is considered as primary key. Why Permission ID is not considered too ?
*snapshot is attached for convenience*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only Primary key columns are marked by a key in the design view, `foreign keys are not marked`. Too see all the keys in your table, left click on your table in the Object Explorer, It will show you a folder with name Key, Open this folder, it will show you all the keys for this table.
In your case I thought the problem is caused by the foreign keys if you run your query without foreign keys it will show both of your columns as Primary key. I tested it

```
create table Accounts_RolePermissions
(
  RoleID int not null,
  PermissionID int not null,
  Primary key(RoleID,PermissionID),
--Foreign key(RoleID) references Accounts_Roles(RoleID),
--Foreign key(PermissionID) references Accounts_Permissions(PermissionID)
)
```